# Scaling images in HTML using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to create a HTML page that can be re sized to most modern resolutions, I'm using % for all my div containers and they are scaling nicely but I have images in these containers and they are staying the same size.

I don't want the images to lose their aspect ratio but I need them to re size to fit in the containers. My example works fine on a 4:3 ratio screen but on a widescreen the images are being cut off. The image I'm using is 213px wide x 300px high. If I have to use js to solve then that's ok.

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:2%;left:2%;overflow:hidden;height:38%;width:12%;text-align:center;border:.15em solid #000;">
   <div style="padding:1% 1% 5% 1%;font-size:90%;font-family:'trebuchet MS', verdana, arial, sans-serif;color:#000;"><b>TEST</b></div>

   <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block;">
      <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Black" />
   </div>
   <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block;">
      <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Black" />
   </div>
   <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block;">
      <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Black" />
   </div>
   <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block;">
      <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Black" />
   </div>
   <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block;">
      <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Black" />
   </div>
   <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block;">
      <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Black" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please.

Comment: forgot i could upload images easily :s here it is in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Cc4FW/1/  as you can see if you change the dimensions of the output window the box dynamically changes size but the images stay the same size, I need them to change size so they always fit in the box while keeping their aspect ratio and being as large as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this one myself, I give the container div a height and width then all other divs and images below only get a height, this makes the screen size dynamic, I had to use display:-moz-inline-block to get the images to centre in the container div. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/mb5T4/2/ re size the result screen into a typical ratio (4:3, 5:4, 16:9) and all the images resize in the div.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have [a post](http://scratchpaper.tk/blog/preserve-an-html-elements-aspect-ratio/) about preserving HTML aspect ratio, [try giving this a shot](http://jsfiddle.net/QmCkY/):

HTML:

```
<div id="container">                      <!--base wrapper-->
    <div id="vertical"></div>             <!--flexible vertical component-->
    <div id="ratioElement">content</div>  <!--fit to wrapper element-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

#vertical{
    margin-top:50%;     /* 2:1 ratio (#container width : #vertical height) */
}

#ratioElement{          
    position:absolute;  /*this would be the <img>*/
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:#069;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use 1 image in a row then you should code like below.

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:2%;left:2%;overflow:hidden;height:38%;width:12%;text-align:center;border:.15em solid #000;">
  <div style="padding:1% 1% 5% 1%;font-size:90%;font-family:'trebuchet MS', verdana, arial, sans-serif;color:#000;"><b>TEST</b></div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block; float:left; clear:left""> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block; float:left; clear:left""> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block; float:left; clear:left""> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block; float:left; clear:left""> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block; float:left; clear:left""> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:44%;display:inline-block; float:left; clear:left""> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeh I'm trying to get it to scale 2 columns of images, 3 images on each column.

Comment: then you should use width 32%

Comment: changing the width still gives me a fixed size image as my example does, if I manually change the size of the screen the image stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery Resiable :
[JQuery UI Resizable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable)

$(selector).resizable(...);

There is multiple examples.

Comment: I'm looking into this but it seems to be more for user input resizing more than dynamic resizing.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:2%;left:2%;overflow:hidden;height:38%;width:12%;text-align:center;border:.15em solid #000;">
  <div style="padding:1% 1% 5% 1%;font-size:90%;font-family:'trebuchet MS', verdana, arial, sans-serif;color:#000;"><b>TEST</b></div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:30%;display:inline-block; float:left;"> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:30%;display:inline-block; float:left;"> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:30%;display:inline-block; float:left;"> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:30%;display:inline-block; float:left;"> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:30%;display:inline-block; float:left;"> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
  <div style="padding:1%;width:30%;display:inline-block; float:left;"> <img src="black_card.jpg" style="max-width:100%; alt="Black" /> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi cgvector this gave me a 3 column 2 row block, on my screen anyway. I have put your code modified on jsfiddle to show how the images get cut off in resizing. http://jsfiddle.net/rRYcX/

Comment: I've attached an image of the problem, the top one is emulating a 4:3 environment and the bottom is 16:9, the bottom one has the images cut off instead of them shrinking to fit. http://imgur.com/pJT0i

Answer (score 0):

remove height from first line....

Comment: but then the box doesn't scale with the window, the box height and width is relative to the window size.

Comment: when you remove height check problem solved... you are also using overflow hidden that's why your last image cut...

Comment: if I remove the height, the box does not scale with the window, the height of the box stays the same size, so on a 4:3 monitor it will be 38% height of the screen but on a 16:9 it's ~60% of the height of the screen. Keeping the height property and removing the overflow:hidden just makes the images overflow over the box as it's size is adjusted.